# Is there any way to get the values of individual rows when using group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following rows in the table named Stuff:

```
id1: Id1, id2: Id2, name: Name, something: Something1;
id1: Id1, id2: Id2, name: Name, something: Something2;
```

I use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Stuff 
WHERE id1= Id1 AND id2 = Id2
GROUP BY id1, id2
```

It will return

```
Id1, Id2, Name, Something2
```

Is there any way for me to find what the 'something' column contained for the other rows, mainly "Something1" in this case? or an enumeration of all the values?

Comment: Either you want to group or you don't. Now which is it? (This is why I really hate how MySQL allows non-aggregates in `GROUP BY`)

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing a sqlfiddle or at least proper of DDLs together with the desired result set.

Comment: What do you want to be displayed for that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/) to get comma-separated list of values from column:

```
SELECT id1, id2, GROUP_CONCAT(something)
FROM Stuff 
WHERE id1= Id1 AND id2 = Id2
GROUP BY id1, id2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try after lunch and post the outcome.